# Where is the MySql table data stored (Mac)?

Tags: mysql, macos, dropbox

I am working on syncing my MySql database on two computers (using dropbox with symlinks). The current database information is stored here: /usr/local/mysql/data

When syncing the db, only the database displays along with the table names, but the data does not display. Is there another place that data is stored?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB tables?  If so then the actual table data will be stored elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? Do you mean it doesn't show data files, or that another computer can't find the data, or what?

Comment: @Eric yes I am (not on all tables but most). Do you know where that data is stored?

Comment: @ughoavgfhw - When syncing the MySql db, on the other computer syncing the db shows the db with the table structure but no data. The question is, where is the data stored if not in the db folder or any folders in the "data" folder.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

well... if you type

```
show variables where Variable_name ='datadir';
```

you will see something like

```
+---------------+---------------+
| Variable_name | Value         |
+---------------+---------------+
| datadir       | /path/to/data |
+---------------+---------------+
```

But to access them manually, you'll need administrator privileges

Comment: This shows where the data directory is which I have been able to access. Within that data directory is the database which doesn't seem to contain all the table data which is the problem. Any ideas?